# how to make a custom signal bar using j2me?

Tags: java-me

First of all, I'm trying to create the Symbian UI from scratch.  But j2me comes with a fixed signal bar.  Can I change it?  Second, is it possible to create the UI using j2me?

Answer (score 1):

In s60 2nd edition phones j2me provides a system property to get the signal strength that is:

```
System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.networksignal");
```

It gives the value as `<number of bars>` (amount in dBM) e.g. 6 (95dBM) or something.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this at all using J2ME, as there is no way to find out the current signal strength.

However you can do this in native Symbian using the [`CTelephony`](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/TSS000881_-_Measuring_signal_strength_using_CTelephony) class.

Comment: can u explain more plz ... im working on s60 symbian platform .
plz give me links or tutorials ... any useful link